# How to simulate $.ajax array POST request with Java

Tags: java, javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to simulate ajax post request with java program.

The simulation works but if I post an array, it comes back as a string.

I'm using Guava:

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

data.put(URLEncoder.encode("affected_ids[]", "UTF-8"), URLEncoder.encode(Joiner.on(":").join(arrIds), "UTF-8"));
data.put("select_all", "true");

String d = Joiner.on("&").withKeyValueSeparator("=").join(data);
```

The content of d looks like:

```
select_all=false&affected_ids%5B%5D=504728%3A121741%3A121742%3A124908%3A316787%3A560950%3A560955%3A560957%3A560958%3A560960%3A516653%3A504729%3A504732%3A504741%3A504748%3A504749%3A552317%3A552320%3A552321%3A552324
```

And it transformed into PHP string:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(139) "504728:121741:121742:124908:316787:560950:560955:560957:560958:560960:516653:504729:504732:504741:504748:504749:552317:552320:552321:552324"
}
```

I have try different delimiters: "," and " ", but with no luck.

What is a correct format for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want PHP to automatically recognize the data as array, you have to sent multiple parameters with the same name, each ending in `[]`.

For example:

```
foo[]=1&foo[]=2
```

will be accessible in PHP as `$_GET['foo']`, returning the array `array(1,2)`.

More information can be found in [Variables From External Sources](https://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) and [How do I create arrays in a HTML `<form>`?](https://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) .